# Laravel 5: Access custom route property

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to access a custom route parameter, same way as route "name": `'cache'=>true`

```
Route::GET('tools/languages/{page?}', array('uses'=> 'Tools@list_languages', 'as'=>'list_languages', 'cache'=>true));
```

How to access `cache` value from Controller?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending @Exprator answer, you could access the parameter in your controller as

```
public function list_languages(Request $request)
{
    $request->route()->getAction()['cache']; // returns true
}
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getAction

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get your Route parameter from Middleware.

In your middleware you can get "matched route object" like this :

```
class MyMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $matchedRouteObject = $request->route();
        $next($request);
    }
}
```

See `print_r($request->route())` there is a property that named action in this Route object. action property has all parameters of matched Route.

```
routes/web.php :

Route::get('tools/languages/{page?}', [
    'uses' => 'Tools@list_languages',
    'middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware',
    'cache' => 'value'
]);
```

app/Http/Middleware/MyMiddleware.php :

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class MyMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $matchedRouteObject = $this->route();
        $deedVariable = $mathedRouteObject->action['cache']; // here you got your variable.
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```